# what do these commands do

Tags: macros, errors, catcodes

Could anyone explain what the commands

- `\@tempcntb`
- `\count@\@ne`
- `\@curtab`

For reference, I found them on [How to produce a list of prime numbers in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134305/how-to-produce-a-list-of-prime-numbers-in-latex)

i do understand that i can create new counts with

```
\catcode`\@=11 %makeatletter

\newcount\@tempcntb
\newcount\@curtab

\catcode`\@=12 %makeatother
```

but i don't see it appear in the macro, so i don't really understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked to the question but I assume you mean this code from my answer

```
\makeatletter
\def\primes#1#2{{%
  \def\comma{\def\comma{, }}%
  \count@\@ne\@tempcntb#2\relax\@curtab#1\relax
  \@primes}}
\def\@primes{\loop\advance\count@\@ne
\expandafter\ifx\csname p-\the\count@\endcsname\relax
\ifnum\@tempcntb<\count@\else
  \ifnum\count@<\@curtab\else\comma\the\count@\fi\fi\else\repeat
\@tempcnta\count@\loop\advance\@tempcnta\count@
\expandafter\let\csname p-\the\@tempcnta\endcsname\@ne
\ifnum\@tempcnta<\@tempcntb\repeat
\ifnum\@tempcntb>\count@\expandafter\@primes\fi}
\makeatother
```

`\@tempcntb` and `\@currtab` are scratch count registers that are already defined by latex so you do not need `\newcount` (the first one intented for temporary use like this, the second one less so, it is normally used by tabbing

`\count@\@ne` is primitive syntax which sets the counter to 1.

Answer (score 2):

`\@tempcntb` is a scratch counter allocated by the LaTeX kernel, so it's always available.

It's similar for `\count@`, which uses `\count255` and is historically a scratch register.

`\@curtab` is instead a counter used in the code for `tabbing` and should *not* be used otherwise. (Not a capital sin in the particular usage, but not good programming style nonetheless.)

The available scratch counters in LaTeX are

```
\count@
\@tempcnta
\@tempcntb
```

Comment: tabbing is useless anyway so may as well use its counter for something:-) (although tabbing uses this globally but so long as you  don't try to interleave a sieve calculation with laying out tabbing it's safe enough (although I admit a slightly odd choice I made at the time)