# LaTeX3 - Loop on integers

Tags: expl3, latex3

The code below try to implement the Eratosthenes' sieve, but the boolean tests fail: in the M(not)WE below, max integer is 4 so integers greater than 4 should be ignored. What am I missing?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_row_int
\int_new:N \l_col_int

\NewDocumentCommand\eratosthenes{ O{#2}m }{   
    \seq_new:N \l_notprime_seq
    
    \int_new:N  \l_tested_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_tested_int { 1 }
    
    \int_new:N  \l_striked_int

    \int_new:N  \l_max_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_max_int { #2*#2 }
    
    \int_do_while:nn {
%        \l_tested_int <= #2
        % The following inefficient test shows one of my problem.
        \l_tested_int <= \l_max_int 
    } {
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l_tested_int = 1 {
            STRIKE ~ ME: ~ 1
            \seq_put_left:Nn \l_notprime_seq 1
        } {
            \seq_if_in:NnF \l_notprime_seq \l_tested_int {
                \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { 2*\l_tested_int }
                
                \int_do_while:nn {
                    \l_striked_int <= \l_max_int
                } {
%                    \seq_if_in:NnF \l_notprime_seq \l_striked_int {
                        \\ STRIKE ~ ME: ~ \int_use:N \l_striked_int
                        \seq_put_left:Nn \l_notprime_seq {\l_striked_int}
%                    }
    
                    \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { \l_striked_int + \l_tested_int }         
                }
            }
        }
        
        \int_incr:N \l_tested_int
        
%        \int_show:N \l_tested_int
%        \int_show:N \l_max_int
        
%        \seq_show:N \l_notprime_seq
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\eratosthenes{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: plant `\int_show:N`  everywhere to check the logic. And correct the naming of your variables, it should be `\l_my_max_int` and `\l_my_striked_int`.

Comment: Renaming done. I'm going to start gardening.

Comment: If the only check per `\bool_if:nTF` you need is one `\int_compare_p:n`, don't use `\bool_if:nTF`, but instead `\int_compare:nNnTF` or `\int_compare:nTF` (the former if you don't need `<=` but only `<`, it is much faster).

Comment: Such a shame... My problem is indeed with `\bool_do_while:nn { \int_compare_p:n {\l_striked_int <= \l_max_int } }`.

Comment: I have missed things like `int_do_while`. I will play with this now...

Comment: @Skillmon I have tried to use the `INT` primitives, but the problem does not seem to be solved.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer may complain my l3 code is not fully idiomatic  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134320/1090

Comment: In fact I got confused with `do_while` and `while_do`. I'll be inoculated in future. I'll answer my question in a few minutes...

Comment: Does it make sense to have `do_while` and `do_until` ? There are synonyms in a sense. `do_while PREDICATE <===> do_until NOT PREDICATE`. No?

Comment: That was not about a problem, they'll do the same, `\bool_if:nTF` is just much slower if you only use it on a single predicate.

Comment: OK. So this can be useful with predicates like `a < b` to obtain quickly `do_until a >= b` via `do_while a < b`. This should be indicated clearly in the `interface3` PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic solution for the loops. `\int_while_do` must be used instead of `\int_do_while`. It remains to make efficient the use of the sequence of integers that does not work here, even if this gives a correct "visual" algorithm. SEe below for a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_row_int
\int_new:N \l_col_int

\NewDocumentCommand\eratosthenes{ O{#2}m }{   
    \seq_new:N \l_notprime_seq
    
    \int_new:N  \l_tested_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_tested_int { 1 }
    
    \int_new:N  \l_striked_int

    \int_new:N  \l_max_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_max_int { #2*#2 }
   
    \int_while_do:nn {
%        \l_tested_int <= #2
%        The following inefficient test shows one of my problem.
        \l_tested_int <= \l_max_int 
    } {
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l_tested_int = 1 {
            \\ \quad STRIKE ~ THIS: ~ 1
            \seq_put_left:Nn \l_notprime_seq 1
        } {
            \seq_if_in:NnTF \l_notprime_seq \l_tested_int {
                \\ PRIME: ~ \int_use:N \l_tested_int
            } {
                \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { 2*\l_tested_int }
                
                \int_while_do:nn {
                    \l_striked_int <= \l_max_int
                } {
%                    \seq_if_in:NnF \l_notprime_seq \l_striked_int {
                        \\ \quad STRIKE ~ ME: ~ \int_use:N \l_striked_int
                        \seq_put_left:Nn \l_notprime_seq {\l_striked_int}
%                    }
    
                    \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { \l_striked_int + \l_tested_int }         
                }
            }
        }
        
        \int_incr:N \l_tested_int
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\noindent \eratosthenes{3}

\end{document}
```

This code correctly prints.

```
STRIKE THIS: 1
STRIKE ME: 4 
STRIKE ME: 6 
STRIKE ME: 8 
STRIKE ME: 6 
STRIKE ME: 9 
STRIKE ME: 8
```

### Final version striking numbers only once

Here is the code I was looking for. This makes an interesting `LaTeX3` exercise.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand\drawstrike{ mm } {  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        remember picture, 
        overlay
    ]
        \draw[
            very thick, 
            red, 
            opacity = 0.3
        ] 
        ([xshift=-3pt]this-#1-#2.north west)
        --
        ([xshift=3pt]this-#1-#2.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_row_int
\int_new:N \l_col_int

\NewDocumentCommand\strikeme{ mm } {
    \int_set:Nn \l_row_int { \int_div_truncate:nn {#2}{#1} }
    \int_set:Nn \l_col_int { \int_mod:nn {#2} {#1}}
    
    \int_compare:nNnTF \l_col_int = 0 {
        \int_set:Nn \l_col_int { #1 }
    } {
        \int_set:Nn \l_row_int { \l_row_int + 1}
    }

    \drawstrike{\int_use:N \l_row_int}{\int_use:N \l_col_int}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\eratosthenes{ O{#2}m }{   
    $\AutoNiceMatrix[
        hvlines, 
        columns - width = auto,
        name            = this
    ]{
        #2-#2
    }{
        \cellval{#2}{\arabic{iRow}}{\arabic{jCol}}
    }$

    \seq_new:N \l_notprime_seq
    
    \int_new:N  \l_tested_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_tested_int { 1 }
    
    \int_new:N  \l_striked_int

    \int_new:N  \l_max_int
    \int_set:Nn \l_max_int { #2*#2 }
    
    \int_while_do:nn {
         \l_tested_int <= #2
    } {
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l_tested_int = 1 {
            \strikeme{#2}{1}
            \seq_put_left:Nn \l_notprime_seq 1
        } {
            \seq_if_in:NxF \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_tested_int} {
                \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { 2*\l_tested_int }
                
                \int_while_do:nn {
                    \l_striked_int <= \l_max_int
                } {
                    \seq_if_in:NxF \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_striked_int} {
                        \strikeme{#2}{\int_use:N \l_striked_int}
                        \seq_put_left:Nx \l_notprime_seq {\int_use:N \l_striked_int}
                    }
    
                    \int_set:Nn \l_striked_int { \l_striked_int + \l_tested_int }         
                }
            }
        }
        
        \int_incr:N \l_tested_int
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\cellval{ mmm }{    
    \int_eval:n{#3 + #1*(#2 - 1)}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\eratosthenes{10}

\end{document}
```