# drawing patterns based on prime factorization

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

can someone help me generate code to type the diagram for any given natural number based on its prime factorization such as these diagrams[image]

consider the next number 36 and its prime factorization, $36=3^2\cdot 2^2$, writing the primes in descending order... then, start with the pattern for a 3, which is 3 circles 120 degrees apart, now, replace each circle with 3 more circles in the same pattern to account for the $3^2$, this part would look like the pattern for 9 which is also $3^2$. now.. to finish the pattern for 36, we take the pattern for 9 and in each circle replace it with the pattern for 4... that is each of the 9 circles gets replaced with 4 tinier circles arranged in the same pattern as the pattern for 4

Comment: I can help. What am I looking at ? Can you make it a proper question? I don't even know what to draw and why

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is probably relevant: [How to automatically draw tree diagram of prime factorization with LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131689/32888)

Comment: thx @percusse I edited the question

Comment: The algorithm is described here http://mathlesstraveled.com/2012/10/05/factorization-diagrams/

Comment: Also, a JavaScript implementation (not mine), which can be a starting point for a luatex or tikz implementation, here: http://jsfiddle.net/FEKX2/3/

Comment: thank you @JLDiaz  that's helpful,  I was hoping to includes these using Tikz or pstricks inside a latex document, seems to me some else might have already done this...

Comment: I saw this and thought "I must remember that when I teach about factorisation", closely followed by "I hope that someone figures out how to do it so that I can steal^H^H^H^H^Huse their code."

Comment: BTW, 1 is not a prime.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

(See update at the end for an alternative output)

Done with Lualatex and tikz, simply converting the code from [this javascript fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FEKX2/3/)

This is a sample result for number 36:

[image: Result]

Which was generated with:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
\draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\primediagram{36}{2.5}{2.5}{2.5};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The macro `\primediagram` receives four parameters. The first one is the number to represent. The remaining three are the center and radius of the diagram to be generated.

A more interesting example:

[image: Result2]

Produced by a tikz loop:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
\foreach \y in {0,...,6} {
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4} {
    \draw(3.1*\x,3.1*\y) rectangle +(3,3);
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\number}{\x+5*\y}
    \primediagram{\number}{3.1*\x+1.55}{3.1*\y+1.55}{1.3};
    \node[black!50, below right] at (3.1*\x, 3.1*\y)  {\number};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

## The complete code

To produce these figures, three files are required:

### primediagram.sty

This one simply defines the tex macro which interfaces with the lua code:

```
% This is primediagram.sty
\directlua{dofile("primediagram.lua")}
\newcommand{\primediagram}[4]{
    \directlua{draw(#1,#2,#3,#4)}
}
```

### primediagram.lua

This one contains the lua code which actually performs the computations and outputs the required `\draw` commands for tikz. It is a direct translation to lua of the mentioned [javascript code](http://jsfiddle.net/FEKX2/3/).

```lua
-- This is primediagram.lua
local smallfirst = false
local off2 = 0

function circle(cx, cy, s) 
    tex.print(string.format("\\fill (%f, %f) circle(%f);", cx, cy, s))
end

function draw(N, cx, cy, s)
  if N==0 then
    return
  end
  if N==1 then
     circle(cx,cy,s)
  else
    local f, r, d, oy, x, y
    f = primefactor(N)
    if f == 2 then
        oy = 0;
        if N % 4 == 0 then
            f = 4;
            r = 2 * s / (f + 2);
            d = f * s / (f + 2);
        else 
            f = 2;
            r = 0.75 * 2 * s / (2 + 2);
            d = 2 * s / (2 + 2);
        end
    else
        r = 2 * s / (f + 2);
        d = f * s / (f + 2);
        oy = d / 2 * (1 - math.cos(math.pi / f));
    end
    for i = 0, f do
        x = math.sin(math.pi + 2 * math.pi * (i + 0.5) / f + off2);
        y = math.cos(math.pi + 2 * math.pi * (i + 0.5) / f + off2);
        draw(N / f, cx + x * d, cy - y * d + oy, r);
    end
  end
end

local primes = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 
    47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 
    113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 
    191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 
    263, 269, 271}

function primefactor(N) 
    local ans = N;
    for i,pi in pairs(primes) do
        if N % pi == 0 then
            ans = pi;
            if smallfirst then
                return ans
            end
        end
    end
    return ans
end
```

## The main document

You only need to include the `sty` package, as for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{primediagram}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
\foreach \y in {0,...,6} {
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4} {
    \draw(3.1*\x,3.1*\y) rectangle +(3,3);
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\number}{\x+5*\y}
    \primediagram{\number}{3.1*\x+1.55}{3.1*\y+1.55}{1.3};
    \node[black!50, below right] at (3.1*\x, 3.1*\y)  {\number};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the figure already shown.

## Update: Rotating sub-groups

If each sub-groups is rotated according to the angle at which it is drawn, the output is different, nicer, and more close to the one shown by the OP. I also removed the black filling of the dots:

[image: New result]

This is the new code (only `primediagram.lua` has to be replaced):

```lua
-- This is primediagram.lua
local smallfirst = false
local off2 = 0

function circle(cx, cy, s) 
    tex.print(string.format("\\draw (%f, %f) circle(%f);", cx, cy, s))
end

function draw(N, cx, cy, s, a)
  if N==0 then
    return
  end
  if N==1 then
     circle(cx,cy,s)
  else
    local f, r, d, x, y, off
    off = 0
    a = a or 0
    tex.print(string.format("\\begin{scope}[xshift=%fcm, yshift=-%fcm, rotate=%f]", cx, cy, a))
    f = primefactor(N)
    if f == 2 then
        oy = 0;
        if N % 4 == 0 then
            f = 4;
            r = 2 * s / (f + 2);
            d = f * s / (f + 2);
        else 
            f = 2;
            r = 0.75 * 2 * s / (2 + 2);
            d = 2 * s / (2 + 2);
            off = math.pi/2
        end
    else
        r = 2 * s / (f + 2);
        d = f * s / (f + 2);
    end
    for i = 0, f-1 do
        local angle = math.pi + 2 * math.pi * (i + 0.5) / f + off
        x = math.sin(angle);
        y = math.cos(angle);
        draw(N / f, x * d, y * d , r, angle*180/math.pi+180);
    end
    tex.print("\\end{scope}")
  end
end

local primes = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 
    47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 
    113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 
    191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 
    263, 269, 271}

function primefactor(N) 
    local ans = N;
    for i,pi in pairs(primes) do
        if N % pi == 0 then
            ans = pi;
            if smallfirst then
                return ans
            end
        end
    end
    return ans
end
```

Comment: very nice, beautifully done!  this is exactly what I was looking for, just a minor point on your modified primediagram.lua version the powers of 2 are not showing up correctly, for example, the numbers 32,16, 8 and 4  are showing up as if 4 was a prime number... then that affects all the numbers with powers-of-two factors

Comment: This is made on purpose, since a group of four dots is easier to visually "parse" than two groups of two, as described in http://mathlesstraveled.com/2012/10/05/factorization-diagrams/ (who had first the idea of this kind of representation, aparently)

Comment: I see, yes even on my original file, the special treatment of 2 show up there... thanks!

Comment: Superb.  Beautiful example of using Lua to do the heavy lifting and TeX to do the beautification.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a `tikzmath` solution.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=147mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{
  % draw diagram for \n centered at (\x,\y) with radius \r
  function primediagram(\n,\x,\y,\r){
    int \n, \largest;
    \largest = \n;
    if \n != 4 then {% 4 is considered as particular case
      % find the largest prime divisor
      for \d in {61,59,53,47,43,41,37,31,29,23,19,17,13,11,7,5,3,2}{
        if \d < \n && \largest == \n && abs(\n/\d - div(\n,\d)) < .001 then{
          \largest = \d;
        };
      };
    };
    % if \n is prime or 4, draw the circles, else recursion ...
    \step = 360/\largest;
    for \i in {1,...,\largest}{
      \a = (\n==2||\n==8||\n==32)? 0:((\n==4)? 45:90); % aesthetic adjustment
      \newx = \n==1 ? 0 : \x+cos(\a+\i*\step)*\r;
      \newy = \n==1 ? 0 : \y+sin(\a+\i*\step)*\r;
      if \largest == \n then{
        {\fill (\newx,\newy) circle(1.8*\r/\largest);};
      }
      else {
        primediagram(\n/\largest,\newx,\newy,\r/\largest);
      };
    };
  };
}
\begin{document}
  \foreach \n in {1,...,35}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
      \path (2.1,-2.1) rectangle (-2.1,2.1);
      \draw (2,-2) rectangle (-2,2) node[red,below right]{\n};
      \tikzmath{primediagram(\n,0,0,1);};
    \end{tikzpicture}\linebreak[0]%
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]