# Not able to compile the given codes

Tags: forest

when i go through,

[How to automatically draw tree diagram of prime factorization with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131689/how-to-automatically-draw-tree-diagram-of-prime-factorization-with-latex)

and trying to compile the following codes to get the given outputs in the answer but unfortunately facing some errors.

Can somebody help me? what is the mistake that i am making.

**Codes:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,mathtools,siunitx}
\makeatletter
\def\ifNum#1{\ifnum#1\relax
  \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo\else
  \expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo\fi}
\forestset{
  num content/.style={
    delay={
      content/.expanded={\noexpand\num{\forestoption{content}}}}},
  pt@prime/.style={draw, circle},
  pt@start/.style={},
  pt@normal/.style={},
  start primeTree/.style={%
    /utils/exec=%
      % \pt@start holds the current minimum factor, we'll start with 2
      \def\pt@start{2}%
      % \pt@result will hold the to-be-typeset factorization, we'll start with
      % \pgfutil@gobble since we don't want a initial \times
      \let\pt@result\pgfutil@gobble
      % \pt@start@cnt holds the number of ^factors for the current factor
      \def\pt@start@cnt{0}%
      % \pt@lStart will later hold "l"ast factor used
      \let\pt@lStart\pgfutil@empty,
    alias=pt-start,
    pt@start/.try,
    delay={content/.expanded={$\noexpand\num{\forestove{content}}
                            \noexpand\mathrlap{{}= \noexpand\pt@result}$}},
    primeTree},
  primeTree/.code=%
    % take the content of the node and save it in the count
    \c@pgf@counta\forestove{content}\relax
    % if it's 2 we're already finished with the factorization
    \ifNum{\c@pgf@counta=2}{%
      % add the factor
      \pt@addfactor{2}%
      % finalize the factorization of the result
      \pt@addfactor{}%
      % and set the style to the prime style
      \forestset{pt@prime/.try}%
    }{%
      % this simply calculates content/2 and saves it in \pt@end
      % this is later used for an early break of the recursion since no factor
      % can be greater then content/2 (for integers of course)
      \edef\pt@content{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
      \divide\c@pgf@counta2\relax
      \advance\c@pgf@counta1\relax % to be on the safe side
      \edef\pt@end{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
      \pt@do}}

%%% our main "function"
\def\pt@do{%
  % let's test if the current factor is already greather then the max factor
  \ifNum{\pt@end<\pt@start}{%
    % great, we're finished, the same as above
    \expandafter\pt@addfactor\expandafter{\pt@content}%
    \pt@addfactor{}%
    \def\pt@next{\forestset{pt@prime/.try}}%
  }{%
    % this calculates int(content/factor)*factor
    % if factor is a factor of content (without remainder), the result will
    % equal content. The int(content/factor) is saved in \pgf@temp.
    \c@pgf@counta\pt@content\relax
    \divide\c@pgf@counta\pt@start\relax
    \edef\pgf@temp{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
    \multiply\c@pgf@counta\pt@start\relax
    \ifNum{\the\c@pgf@counta=\pt@content}{%
      % yeah, we found a factor, add it to the result and ...
      \expandafter\pt@addfactor\expandafter{\pt@start}%
      % ... add the factor as the first child with style pt@prime
      % and the result of int(content/factor) as another child.
      \edef\pt@next{\noexpand\forestset{%
        append={[\pt@start, pt@prime/.try]},
        append={[\pgf@temp, pt@normal/.try]},
        % forest is complex, this makes sure that for the second child, the
        % primeTree style is not executed too early (there must be a better way).
        delay={
          for descendants={
            delay={if n'=1{primeTree, num content}{}}}}}}%
    }{%
      % Alright this is not a factor, let's get the next factor
      \ifNum{\pt@start=2}{%
        % if the previous factor was 2, the next one will be 3
        \def\pt@start{3}%
      }{%
        % hmm, the previos factor was not 2,
        % let's add 2, maybe we'll hit the next prime number
        % and maybe a factor
        \c@pgf@counta\pt@start
        \advance\c@pgf@counta2\relax
        \edef\pt@start{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
      }%
      % let's do that again
      \let\pt@next\pt@do
    }%
  }%
  \pt@next
}

%%% this builds the \pt@result macro with the factors
\def\pt@addfactor#1{%
  \def\pgf@tempa{#1}%
  % is it the same factor as the previous one
  \ifx\pgf@tempa\pt@lStart
    % add 1 to the counter
    \c@pgf@counta\pt@start@cnt\relax
    \advance\c@pgf@counta1\relax
    \edef\pt@start@cnt{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
  \else
    % a new factor! Add the previous one to the product of factors
    \ifx\pt@lStart\pgfutil@empty\else
      % as long as there actually is one, the \ifnum makes sure we do not add ^1
      \edef\pgf@tempa{\noexpand\num{\pt@lStart}\ifnum\pt@start@cnt>1 
                                           ^{\noexpand\num{\pt@start@cnt}}\fi}%
      \expandafter\pt@addfactor@\expandafter{\pgf@tempa}%
    \fi
    % setup the macros for the next round
    \def\pt@lStart{#1}% <- current (new) factor
    \def\pt@start@cnt{1}% <- first time
  \fi
}
%%% This simply appends "\times #1" to \pt@result, with etoolbox this would be
%%% \appto\pt@result{\times#1}
\def\pt@addfactor@#1{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\pt@result\expandafter{\pt@result \times #1}}

%%% Our main macro:
%%% #1 = possible optional argument for forest (can be tikz too)
%%% #2 = the number to factorize
\newcommand*{\PrimeTree}[2][]{%
  \begin{forest}%
    % as the result is set via \mathrlap it doesn't update the bounding box
    % let's fix this:
    tikz={execute at end scope={\pgfmathparse{width("${}=\pt@result$")}%
                         \path ([xshift=\pgfmathresult pt]pt-start.east);}},
    % other optional arguments
    #1
    % And go!
    [#2, start primeTree]
  \end{forest}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\PrimeTree{36}
\PrimeTree{90}
\PrimeTree{112}
\PrimeTree{612}
\PrimeTree{7875}
\PrimeTree{22230}
\PrimeTree{1073741824}
\PrimeTree{2147483644}
\end{document}
```

**errors:**

```
line 143: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{36}
line 143: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{36}
line 143: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{36}
line 143: Missing $ inserted. \PrimeTree{36}
line 143: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{36}
line 143: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{36}
line 143: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{36}
line 145: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{112}
line 145: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{112}
line 145: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{112}
line 145: Missing $ inserted. \PrimeTree{112}
line 145: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{112}
line 145: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{112}
line 145: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{112}
line 146: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{612}
line 146: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{612}
line 146: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{612}
line 146: Missing $ inserted. \PrimeTree{612}
line 146: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{612}
line 146: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{612}
line 146: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{612}
line 147: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{7875}
line 147: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{7875}
line 147: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{7875}
line 147: Missing $ inserted. \PrimeTree{7875}
line 147: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{7875}
line 147: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{7875}
line 147: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{7875}
line 149: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{1073741824}
line 149: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{1073741824}
line 149: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{1073741824}
line 149: Missing $ inserted. \PrimeTree{1073741824}
line 149: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{1073741824}
line 149: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{1073741824}
line 149: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{1073741824}
line 150: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{2147483644}
line 150: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{2147483644}
line 150: Extra }, or forgotten $. \PrimeTree{2147483644}
line 150: Missing $ inserted. \PrimeTree{2147483644}
line 150: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{2147483644}
line 150: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{2147483644}
line 150: Missing } inserted. \PrimeTree{2147483644}
```

Comment: I see the same error. I left a comment on the original question perhaps the author will update.

Comment: Ok. hope that we get quick answer.

Comment: Whatever the cause of this error, it is fixed in the upcoming v2, which will really be published at ctan soon, as I've got some time on my hands again ... until then, please download the latest release candidate manually from https://github.com/sasozivanovic/forest/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem does not occur with the updated version of the package, which is now available on CTAN. (See package author's comments on question. Even if the code produces errors with the latest version, it is exceedingly unlikely it will generate the same errors as the code produced with the relevant version of version 1.)