# Helping using forest for factor tree

Tags: forest

I started using the package forest to create a factor tree (I'm brand new to it. Just looked at another post to get started).

But I am stuck expanding it. Not sure how I would go about.

Current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [16
    [2
      %[#]%
      %[#]%
    ]
    [8
      [4]
      [2]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Current output:

[image]

What I want to finish (expand the 4 and draw a circle around the 2's:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try adding `for tree = {if n children = {0}{circle, draw}{}}` to the options of your tree. You might be interested in [Q131689](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131689).

Comment: I looked at Q131689, but that just seemed excessive. I believe that automates the entire factor tree.

I just want to manually add, don't have too many to make.

Not following what you mean by: "for tree = {if n children = {0}{circle, draw}{}}" where would I put that and what would it do?

Appreciate it!

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you. Then just replace `[4]` with `[4 [2][2]]` and you added the two remaining factors.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked.

Any recommendation on how to circle a number. If it is too many additional steps then probably not worth it. But if it is a quick thing that would be awesome to have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add the remaining factors of `4` just add two `[2]` children to the `[4]`:

```
[4 [2][2]]
```

or with formatting

```
[4
  [2]
  [2]
]
```

Those are exactly the same.

For the leaves (nodes without children) we can use `forest`s in-built check

```
if n children = {0}{<true>}{<false>}
```

This checks if the current node has `0` children and if it does it applies the options `<true>`, otherwise `<false>`.

Since you want this to be checked for all nodes automatically, we put this into `for tree`.

---

And since you probably want to use this for more than one tree, we package it up in a `leaves as circles` key so that you only have to add this option as an option to the `forest` environment. (These options are *not* between `[` and `]` as usual in LaTeX.)

I've adjusted the `inner sep` a bit for these nodes, the default value is a bit too big for `circle`s in my opinion in this case.

---

The options added to these childless leaves are just normal TikZ node options. This now provides an automatic approach.

However, for each child, you can add TikZ (or `forest` keys) after the content of the node after a `,`:

```
[2, red]
```

would add a node with content `2` at the current position in the tree that will be red as if it were `\node [red] {2};`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  leaves as circles/.style={
    for tree={
      if n children = {0}{circle, draw, inner sep=+.15em}{}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} leaves as circles
  [16
    [2]
    [8
      [4
        [2]
        [2]
      ]
      [2]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]