# Two pdfs (screen and print) from one .tex file

Tags: printing, screen, pdfscreen

I want to generate two pdfs from one `.tex` file. There are two packages namely `pdfscreen`and `screen` for creating a document either for print as output or for viewing the pdf generated online.

How can I achieve this by means of a single `.tex` file?

**Edit**

```
\documenclass{book}
\usepackage[print,nopanel]{pdfscreen}
\begin{print}
...some packages name
\end{print}
\begin{screen}
...some packages name
\end{screen}
\begin{document}
This is some example document.
\end{document}
```

When I run `pdflatex filename.tex`, I want to have two pdfs according to packages used in print section and in screen section.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The only `screen` package I can find on CTAN is for LaTeX 2.09. `print` I cannot find at all.

Comment: Just like there are documents in documentation available for print and others for viewing on screen, how can these be achieved together from one .tex file?

Comment: What does `screen` have to do with it? It isn't in your MWE and you could not use it in a LaTeX-2e document. It would be much easier to create two documents with the relevant preambles and then input the main body of the document.

Comment: Those packages do not usually produce two PDFs from a single `pdflatex` run, though. So what you want is not 'just like' that at all ;).

Comment: `pdflatex -jobname=print "\newif\ifprint\printtrue\input{filename.tex}" && pdflatex -jobname=screen "\newif\ifprint\printfalse\input{filename.tex}"`, where your main file is `filename.tex` and it has something like `\ifprint \usepackage{printstuff} \else \usepackage{screenstuff} \fi` for separating out the different "print" and "screen" setups.  I gave a [similar answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134039/8528) once.