# Newline in \def

Tags: line-breaking

I can not solve my problem.
I have definition:

```
\def\mfTitle{askdj asldj asdlk jhasd kjhaslkjd asdas}
```

and I would like add a newline into it:

```
\def\mfTitle{askdj asldj asdlk \newline jhasd kjhaslkjd asdas}
```

but I get an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@normalcr ->\let \reserved@e 
                              \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let ...
l.20 ...fined\relax\else\pdfinfo{ /Title (\mfTitle
                                                  ) /Author (\mfAuthor) /Cre...
```

Is it possible to do it in some easy way? Thanks

**EDIT**
usage of `\mfTitle`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{slovak}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.3} % riadkovanie jeden a pol

% pekne pokope definujeme potrebne udaje
\def\mftitle{Názov Práce}
\def\mfthesistype{Diplomová alebo neviem aká práca}
\def\mfauthor{Študent Autor}
\def\mfadvisor{Dr. Evorubač, ZLe.Sa.}
\def\mfplacedate{Bratislava, 2008}

\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined\relax\else\pdfinfo{ /Title (\mftitle) /Author (\mfauthor) /Creator (PDFLaTeX) } \fi

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.20\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{komlogo-new}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.79\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\sc asd asdasd \\
asd asd, asd a asd \\
asd asd, asd
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\vfill
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
\hrule
\bigskip\bigskip
\centerline{\LARGE\sc\mftitle}
\smallskip
\centerline{(\mfthesistype)}
\bigskip
\bigskip
\centerline{\large\sc\mfauthor}
\bigskip\bigskip
\hrule
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vfill
{\bf Vedúci:} \mfadvisor
\hfill\mfplacedate
\eject % EOP i

\thispagestyle{empty}~\vfill\eject % EOP ii

{~}\vspace{12cm}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}~\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.68\textwidth}
Čestne prehlasujem, že som túto diplomovú prácu vypracoval(a) samostatne s použitím citovaných zdrojov.

\bigskip\bigskip

\hfill\hbox to 6cm{\dotfill}
\end{minipage}
\vfill\eject % EOP iii
~\vfill\eject % EOP iv

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\input 01intro.tex
\input 02dalej.tex

\backmatter

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{literatura}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where are you using that command? Inside some other? Regular paragraph? A minimal document compiles right with it.

Comment: You can try adding `\long`, but without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem, it is difficult to help, as both versions of `\mfTitle` as defined above work fine. For reference [Why don't we always use \long\def instead of \def?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39450/why-dont-we-always-use-long-def-instead-of-def).

Comment: it looks like `\newline`, although a "robust" command, might be being expanded once too often as it goes through multiple uses.  try changing `\newline` to `\protect\newline` in the definition.  (this is just a guess; not guaranteed.)

Comment: not working :( same error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't be using `\def`, but `\newcommand`. The problem is that `\newline` makes no sense when passed to `\pdfinfo`.

In any case you should probably use `\\` rather than `\newline`. The idea is the same, though.

The `\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined` test is obsolete and won't distinguish between DVI or PDF output. Use `\ifpdf` from the `ifpdf` package instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}

\newcommand\mfTitle{askdj asldj asdlk\\ jhasd kjhaslkjd asdas}
\newcommand\mfAuthor{Dusan Plavak}

\ifpdf
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\\}{}% temporarily disable \\
\pdfinfo{ /Title (\mfTitle) /Author (\mfAuthor) /Creator (PDFLaTeX) }
\endgroup
\fi

\begin{document}
\title{\mfTitle}
\author{\mfAuthor}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a possibly better version of your (really bad) template. The `demo` option to `graphicx` is just because I don't have your logo; the package `epsfig` is obsolete. Also `slovak` is obsolete and it's better to go with `babel`. For the info, I used `hyperref`, which knows UTF-8 (with `\pdfinfo` you wouldn't get correct results).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % the demo option is just because I don't have the logo
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\linespread{1.3} % riadkovanie jeden a pol

% pekne pokope definujeme potrebne udaje
\def\mftitle{Názov\\ Práce}
\def\mfthesistype{Diplomová alebo neviem aká práca}
\def\mfauthor{Študent Autor}
\def\mfadvisor{Dr. Evorubač, ZLe.Sa.}
\def\mfplacedate{Bratislava, 2008}

\ifpdf
  \hypersetup{
    pdftitle=\mftitle,
    pdfauthor=\mfauthor,
    pdfcreator=PDFLaTeX,
   }
\fi

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{komlogo-new}
\begin{minipage}{0.79\textwidth}
\centering
\sc asd asdasd \\
asd asd, asd a asd \\
asd asd, asd
\end{minipage}

\vfill
\begin{center}
\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\bigskip\bigskip

{\LARGE\scshape\mftitle\par}

\smallskip

{(\mfthesistype)}

\bigskip\bigskip

{\large\scshape\mfauthor}

\bigskip\bigskip

\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\end{center}
\vfill
{\bfseries Vedúci:} \mfadvisor
\hfill\mfplacedate
\cleardoublepage % EOP i


\vspace*{12cm}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.68\textwidth}

Čestne prehlasujem, že som túto diplomovú prácu vypracoval(a) 
samostatne s použitím citovaných zdrojov.

\bigskip\bigskip

\hspace*{\fill}\makebox[6cm]{\dotfill}
\end{minipage}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

% Next lines are commented because I don't have the files
%\input{01intro.tex}
%\input{02dalej.tex}

\backmatter

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{literatura}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, your solution works if I copy-paste it... but when I am trying use it in my template it is not working. I am beginner with tex so do not understand a lot of things... I updated my question with full template....

Comment: @DusanPlavak You have a very bad template, I should say: it's a mixture of LaTeX and Plain with several deprecated commands.

Comment: Uff, ok, it should be a template for bachelor work... So I guess I will try  it from other point of view... I discard that template and will try to make my own... Any suggestions from where I can learn it?

Comment: @DusanPlavak I provided a better version, that corrects the bad constructions used in what was given to you. I also added a ``\\`` in the title, just to show it works.