# Multi-paragraph footnote in title

Tags: footnotes

I don't know why the footnote doesn't work. It does without `\par`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\title{title%
\footnote{
    para1\par
    para2
}%
}
\author{author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Paragraphing doesn't work very well in footnotes oin general; LaTeX has defined `\par` to have checks that often aren't appropriate in a footnote environment.  Instead of `\par` you can use `\endgraf` which does only the basic positioning, without the extra checks.

Comment: I tries an empty line for a paragraph break but also got an error message. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For why it doesn't work see: [Why don't we always use \long\def instead of \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39450/why-dont-we-always-use-long-def-instead-of-def)

So to fix it, you could redefine `\title` and `\thanks` from `latex.ltx` to be `\long` which will then allow the paragraph break.

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}}
\long\def\thanks#1{%
  \footnotemark
  \protected@xdef\@thanks{%
    \@thanks\protect\footnotetext[\the\c@footnote]{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

But an easier option is just to define your footnote text as a separate macro which gets around the error checking.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\def\titlefootnotetext{para1\par para2}

\title{title\thanks{\titlefootnotetext}}
\author{author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, very well answered with more than one options. I have never used `\def` before.