# When should we use \cs_new...nopar?

Tags: expl3, best-practices

I ask about some of the best practices for programming `expl3` code.

Section 4 of `interface3.pdf` describes functions that define new control sequences that prohibit `\par` in their function parameters (`#1`, `#2`, etc.).
These functions have `_nopar` in their name (e.g. `\cs_new_nopar:Npn`, `\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn`, `\cs_new_nopar:Nn`, etc.)

My question is: When should the programmer instead use the `nopar` alternatives when defining new functions in LaTeX3?

A related question has been discussed here ([Why don't we always use \long\def instead of \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39450/why-dont-we-always-use-long-def-instead-of-def)), but I would like an answer that is more related to `expl3`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The team generally use `nopar` in very limited circumstances

- For low-level implementation of variables, in particular `tl`, which are 'short' macros behind-the-scenes
- For implementation of `ltcmd`, which differentiates 'long' and 'short' arguments at a document level

Beyond that, almost all of the team's code is 'long'. The reason is that there is no performance advantage to 'short' macros. At the same time, `\par` tokens can pop up in many programming contexts, and the 'error handling' aspect of 'short' macros is only really useful at the document level (as already noted).

---

Perhaps of interest is that in LuaTeX there is `\suppresslongerror`, which can turn off the error entirely, and that's the approach taken in ConTeXt.